# Calculate the number of real roots of $x^8-x^5+x^2-x+1 = 0$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials, roots

> Calculate the number of real roots of$$x^8-x^5+x^2-x+1 = 0 .$$

#### My Try

$$\left(x^4-\frac{x}{2}\right)^2+\frac{3}{4}x^2-x+1 = \left(x^4-\frac{x}{2}\right)^2+\frac{3}{4}\left(x^2-\frac{4}{3}x+\frac{4}{3}\right)$$

$$\implies \left(x^4-\frac{x}{2}\right)^2+\frac{3}{4}\left(x-\frac{2}{3}\right)^2+1-\frac{4}{9}>0\quad \forall x\in \mathbb{R}$$

My question is whether any other method like using inequality exists to solve the given question. If yes, then please explain here.

Comment: Very nice try. In your last line, inside the second parentheses it must be $\,x\,$ , not $\,x^2\,$ .

Comment: Usually to compute the number of real roots as you already did yourself inequalities are very useful. Sometimes though the Mean Value Theorem http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_value_theorem is also very useful when you can easily estimate f(x) for given values of x.
And please use more specifying tags, maybe algebra, equations, real polynomials.

Comment: You might also like to read this http://mathoverflow.net/questions/20946/criteria-to-determine-whether-a-real-coefficient-polynomial-has-real-root

Answer (score 10, accepted):

AM-GM Inequality gives us,
$$\large\frac{1}{2} \left(x^{8}+x^{2}\right)\geq x^{5}$$

$$\large\frac{1}{2} \left(x^{2}+1\right)\geq x$$

$$\large\therefore x^{8}+x^{2}+1>\frac{1}{2} \left(x^{8}+x^{2}\right)+\frac{1}{2} \left(x^{2}+1\right)\geq x^{5}+x$$

$$\large\implies x^{8}-x^{5}+x^{2}-x+1> 0$$

Hence there cannot exist any real solution for $\large x$.

Comment: Er... It's safe to assume people can read (or have their zoom adequate). No need for `\large`.

Comment: That works so neatly that it seems as if the polynomial was _designed_ with this solution in mind.

Answer (score 2):

I was curious to see whether even the homely methods we teach early on can resolve this.  Descartes' Rule of Signs tells us that there are 4, 2, or 0 positive real roots and no negative real roots.  So we already know there are at least two complex conjugate pairs of zeroes.

The Rational Zeroes Theorem only suggests the candidates $\pm 1$, which plainly don't work.  Any of the four remaining *prospective* real zeroes must be irrational.

As a polynomial of even degree, $f(x)$ has an absolute extremum; the positive leading coefficient tells us this is an absolute minimum.  The leading term so dominates the behavior of the polynomial that it is only worth looking for that and any real zeroes fairly close to $x = 0$ .  We find  $f( -1 ) = 5 , f ( 0 ) = 1 $, and $f ( 1 ) = 1 $ [ $f(\pm 2)$ are relatively colossal positive values], so the Intermediate Value Theorem isn't much help (though we suspect the function isn't "wiggling around" much in the interval $( -1 , 1 )$ ) .

We can check that, though now we need derivatives:  $f'(x) = 8x^7 - 5x^4 + 2x - 1$ and $f''(x) = 56x^6 - 20x^3 + 2$ .  We can test $f''(x)$ by solving it like a quadratic function with the substitution $t = x^3$ to find that it has no real zeroes.  Hence, $f''(x)$ is *always* positive, making $f(x)$ concave upward everywhere; thus, there is only one "turning point".

We also have $f'(-1) = -16 , f'(0) = -1 ,$ and $f'(1) = +3$, so it seems pretty safe to say the one local minimum in $( 0 , 1 )$ is positive.  So the absolute minimum of $f(x)$ appears to be positive, meaning there are no real zeroes.

(Thank you for the link to MathOverflow.  I have been studying theory of equations on my own and have been interested in the analysis that can be done without resorting to graphing.)